# Why postgresql now() returns always the same result?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, timestamp, timing

I want to time the execution of my code. I use now() to track the elapsed time. My code looks like:

```
DO $$
    DECLARE 
...
    PROGRAMM_TIME_ELAPSED TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO PROGRAMM_TIME_ELAPSED now();
...
    raise notice '% values created in %', VALUES_COUNT, now() - PROGRAMM_TIME_ELAPSED;
END $$;
```

This code prints `... values created in 00:00:00`. Always. No dependancy on how much time is elapsed.

Even beyond that:

```
    raise notice '%', now();
    raise notice '%', now();
    raise notice '%', now();
    raise notice '%', now();
    raise notice '%', now();
```

produces 5 absolutely identical values. E.g. `2019-01-30 12:26:57.195649+00`. A call to a function lasts definetely more than 1 microsecond.

What am I missing? What is the preferable way to do timing in postgres?

Comment: Some databases use the datetime at the beginning of the transaction.  From what you describe, Postgres would seem to do this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: Sure, read the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) about this.